# My input labels will not align to my input type = text

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to align my floating labels with my floating input fields. Of course, I have been searching around but no available answers helped me out.

Find it here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGV6G/1/)

The problem is related to the font-size I am setting for the body-tag. Remove it and you'll see that the label and input is vertically aligned.

How can I fix this (without removing the font-size style for body, my entire application is depending on this one)?

Comment: changing/adding markup is an acceptable option?

Comment: Yes, I have full control of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've a list of fields I would wrap every pair of `label + field` inside a `list-item` and thus applying a basic clearing to `<li>` element like so

```
#addagentform li {
   height: auto; overflow: hidden;
}
```

you achieve the effect. 
see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AGV6G/6/

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why I need those two? First I though the auto was obvious, but testing around with your code made me realize that the overflow was the significant one. Removing height didn't have any effect.

Comment: that rule is a kind of a basic `float clearing`. it's necessary so that each line is not affected by previous floated elements and you can see the both label and field top aligned

Comment: is using clear:both and option instead of the overflow or has it got some kind of side-effect (it works when testing)?

Comment: height declaration isn't needed. Sometimes it's used to trigger haslayout in IE6 who doesn't use overflow: hidden, but then you use something other than "auto" for that. For the font issue, realise that inputs don't seem to inherit those. I re-set font-size on my inputs now for this reason. Re clear:both, clearing and enclosing are two different things. overflow:other-than-visible makes the parent element *enclose* the floats. Clearing only makes next element stay underneath the float, but parent does not necessarily *enclose*. Want example?

Comment: You have already answered my original question but if you don't mind showing me an example I would appreciate it.

Comment: http://stommepoes.nl/floaties.html Go through these pages in any modern browser and then also IE7, so you can see the IE stuff. IE8 might show if it's in "compatibility mode" since it should then invoke Haslayout (otherwise it doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tricky and error-prone floating, just use a simple and logical table, with labels in one column, corresponding input items in another, and you’ll get things done in no time. This will also fix the problem that now the labels can get very, very far from the input items.

```
<form ...>
<table>
  <tr><td><label for="firstname">*Förnamn:</label> 
      <td><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
  <tr>...
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Jukka! WTH? This is as bad as adding lists! Or was that your point? Extra markup is extra markup?

Comment: @stommepoes, adding table markup for tabular data isn’t “extra” markup, and it solves the problem, avoiding a lot of mess being discussed here. No need to play with “hasLayout” or the number of angels on the head of a pin, or a number of browser incompatibilities.

Comment: @jukka To me, forms aren't tabular data, unless the user is actually filling out a table. Nor lists. But to each his own.